# Pythong PuLP Constraints: How to build a recursive constraint

Tags: python, dictionary, model, constraints, pulp

I am building a simple model in PuLp that requires me to build a recursive function as a constraint based on the following  [equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhRlb.png). In PuLp the constraint is written as: `model += lpSum([y[j] + x[j] -z[j]]) == x[j+1]`

However I get Keyerror when running this model. I've tried a few things including creating a blank dictionary, or creating an additional variable to contain the `x[j+1]` list.

How do I write this recursive equation in PulP? Or is there another library which can handle this equation better?

The model was initialized with the following dictionaries and objective function

```
from pulp import *

period = ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4']
z = [200, 0, 0, 500]
x = [50, 100, 100, 300]
cap = [1000, 1000, 1000, 1000]
z_dict = dict(zip(period, z))
x_dict = dict(zip(period, x))
cap_dict = dict(zip(period, cap))
model = LpProblem("Simple Model", LpMinimize)

y = LpVariable.dicts("decision",  period, lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')
b = LpVariable.dicts("binary", period, cat='Binary')

model += (lpSum([15*b[j] for j in period]) + lpSum([y[j]*10 for j in period])) # Objective Function`

for j in period:
    model += lpSum([x[j]]) + y[j] >= z[j]
    model += lpSum([y[j]]) <= lpSum([cap_dict[j]*b[j]])
    model += lpSum([y[j] + x[j] -z[j]]) == x[j+1] # The constraint in question
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your basic problem is that `x[j+1]` causes an out of bounds problem.

With the following changes a result is produced:

```
period = [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

and

```
for j in period:
    model += lpSum([x[j]]) + y[j] >= z[j]
    model += lpSum([y[j]]) <= lpSum([cap_dict[j]*b[j]])
    if j < max(period):
        model += lpSum([y[j] + x[j] -z[j]]) == x[j+1] # The constraint in question
```

Additionally added the following to show the result:

```
model.solve()
print("Status : ", pulp.LpStatus[model.status])
print("Result : ", pulp.value(model.objective))
for v in model.variables():
    print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)
```